# Executing Shell script which contains SQL Plus commands from Java Program

Tags: java, shell, jsch

I have Shell script which executes properly when I run it manually. But I run the shell script through java program, the shell program runs, but it does not update the table and no error also is thrown. Below contains the details of my shell script and link to java program.

Shell Script-

```
echo "started the script execution"
 echo "
            BEGIN
                update <<table_name>> set name='abc';
                commit;
           END;
          /
 "|  sqlplus -s $MD_DB_USER_NAME/$MD_DB_PASS@$MD_DB_SERVER
echo "After executing the update statement"
```

Java Program from which I'm calling shell scipt:
 
http://www.codesandscripts.com/2014/10/java-program-to-execute-shell-scripts-on-remote-server.html.

I think program is with connection to database. Can anyone tell me what it might be

Comment: How do you call the shell script?

Comment: output shell command log to a log file.In that way you will know exactly what is the error.

Comment: Add `echo $MD_DB_USER_NAME/$MD_DB_PASS@$MD_DB_SERVER` to the beginning of the script to see if the variables are set at all. And check the script output. Either by consuming it in the Java or by redirecting the script to a temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above answers. My answer to my question is mentioned below-

Before running through shell script, I was loading a profile file which contained all my DB details etc. So it was working properly. But when I was running through java program, profile file was not loaded. So in 1st line of my shell script I had to add source "profile file path". Now its working properly.